# $_SESSION array empty key

Tags: php, arrays, session

```
<?php session_start();?>

<?php
    !isset($_GET["id"]) ? header("Location: store.php") : $id = $_GET['id'];
?>

<?php
    $_SESSION["items"][$id] = 1; 
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

This outputs

```
    Array
    (
        [items] => Array
            (
                [1] => 1
                [] => 1
                [2] => 1
                [3] => 1
            )
    )
```

There always appears one key empty. Why that key is empty.

Comment: Try clearing out the Session in your browser and test it again.

Comment: Can you add the output of `print_r($_GET)` to your question?

Comment: Do a session_destroy(); and try again

Answer (score 4):

It's this line here:

```
$_SESSION["items"][$id] = 1;
```

if **$id** is undefined, then the undefined key is set to 1, you need to validate the $id before you assign it, a simple way to do this would be:

```
if(isset($id)){
    $_SESSION["items"][$id] = 1;
}
```

Should do the trick :-)

Comment: But if `$_GET["id"]` isn't set, it should redirect to a different page, so he shouldn't have that problem.

Comment: @Shredder - PHP will keep processing the document regardless of headers, it's the client that decides to follow the Location header. So good point! Remember to add an exit(); command after outputting your location header :-)